# my fstream part of the program doesn't compile. and can the ReplaceString part of the program made to execute faster? c++

Tags: c++, string, fstream

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>



/*
    string中の特定文字列をstringで置換する
*/
std::string ReplaceString
(
      std::string String1   // 置き換え対象
    , std::string String2   // 検索対象
    , std::string String3   // 置き換える内容
)
{
    std::string::size_type  Pos( String1.find( String2 ) );

    while( Pos != std::string::npos )
    {
        String1.replace( Pos, String2.length(), String3 );
        Pos = String1.find( String2, Pos + String3.length() );
    }

    return String1;
}

int _tmain
(
      int argc
    , _TCHAR* argv[]
)
{
    FreeConsole();
    std::char data[100];
    std::cout << "filename you want; ";
    std::cin >> data;
    // 標準出力にユニコード出力する
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "Japanese" );
    std::string str, str1 ,str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, str7, str8, str9, str10, str11, str12, str13, str14, str15, str16, str17, str18, str19, str20, str21, str22, str23, str24, str25, str26, str27, str28, str29, str30, str31, str32, str33, str34, str35, str36, str37, str38, str39, str40, str41, str42, str43, str44, str45, str46, str47, str48, str49, str50, str51, str52, str53, str54, str55, str56, str57, str58, str59, str60, str61, str62, str63, str64, str65, str66, str67, str68, str69, str70, str71, str72, str73, str74, str75, str76, str77, str78, str79, str80, str81, str82, str83, str84, str85, str86, str87, str88, str89, str90, str91, str92, str93, str94;
    std::cout << "string you want encrypted:  ";
    std::getline(std::cin , str );
    // stringをstringで置換する
    str1 = ReplaceString(
              str
            , "v"
            , "-9H4VTkhW4-Nnx4"
        );


    // 標準出力へ出力する
    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(data + ".dat");
    outfile << str94 ;
    outfile.close();

    // 正常終了
    return( 0 );
}
```

the error that I am getting is

```
E2272 an identifier is needed "std::char data[100]"
```

Also, there is the replace string code for all the numbers, letters and symbols on the keyboard, which is 94 characters.

It takes more than 3 minutes to encrypt a simple word, like hello.

if there is any way to make this program run faster, please tell me.

Comment: Ain't no such thing as `std::char`. Make it plain `char`

Comment: thanks but then another error came up saying E2085 invalid pointer "outfile.open(data + ".dat");"

Comment: @PY_NEWBIE You should ask only one question at a time. I'd suggest making a second question regarding the speed when your program actually works. Btw, how did you measure the time if it doesn't even compile?

Comment: I got rid of the fstream part.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is a keyword of the C++ language, not an identifier for a type declared in `std`. Therefore you cannot prefix `char` with `std::`. Simply use `char` instead of `std::char`.

However, you are intending to use the array to receive a file name from the user, so there is no reason to use a fixed-size character array at all. Instead define `data` with type `std::string`:

```
std::string data;
```

This also avoids some problems that you are having with the character array. For example `data + ".dat"` is not valid if `data` is of type `char[]`, because addition between character arrays and string literals is simply not defined. With `data` as string however, this works as intended, appending the string literal to a copy of the string `data`.

Comment: error E2034 std::string cannot be converted into a const char* (function main(int, char**))

Comment: @PY_NEWBIE Then you are probably using an old compiler version. You need to enable at least C++11 to use the code without additional modification. Sidenote: You also need to `#include<string>`.

Comment: right now I'm using a borland c++ 5.5.1 compiler which came with the pc

Comment: @PY_NEWBIE That compiler was released in 2000, it is completely out-dated and many things that you would be reading about C++ today will not work in it. You should have a look into Visual Studio or MinGW if you are on Windows.